# how I send more objects with POST in Angular2?

Tags: angular, post

I have 3 objects , 1º -> Data User (name,surname,dni, etc ..) , 2º Data Car (colour, price , etc.) other data.

if I want to send this data with Angular 2+ ->

```
  return this.http.post(url, dataUser, dataCar, otherData, { responseType: 'text' });
```

I get error because I only can send 1 data... but I need to send 2 or 3 or more...

Then I use ->

```
 this.formData = new FormData();
 this.formData.append("dataUser", new Blob([JSON.stringify(dataUser)],
 { type: "application/json" }));
 this.formData.append('dataCar', new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.dataCar)],
 { type: "application/json" }));
 this.formData.append('otherData', new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.otherData)],
 { type: "application/json" }));
```

Now I can send what I want

```
 return this.http.post(url, formData, { responseType: 'text' });
```

But in the code of my server (SpringBoot) I need to add ->

```
 consumes = "multipart/form-data")
```

My question is -> Is it correct ? I parse my Object to Blob because I can't send 3 objects to Server.

Really my server doesn't hope Files -> multipart/form-data.

Then I don't know how I can send multiples Objects with Angular 2+. I find this solution (formData) but I want do a good job.

Comment: Since you add a `FormData` object as payload it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can create one single object of all but its totally depend on backed, how they handle with this input data.

like,

```
 return this.http.post(url, {dataUser: dataUser, dataCar: dataCar, otherData: otherData }, { responseType: 'text' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a single object that contains all your data. Like this

```
const dataObj = {
  dataUser: // required user data here
  dataCar: // required car data here
```

}

And send this single object to the server.

```
return this.http.post(url, dataObj, httpOptions);
```